How to track deleted messages in a group using telegram api
Is there any listener that listens to this event or is it possible to do this in other ways? The main task is to understand which messages have been deleted and mark them as deleted. If there is no listener, can I somehow track it using the chat history and its messages?
there was an attempt to track the event via update , but it doesn’t catch deleted messages

Nope, Bot API does not have any methods to check if a message is deleted or not.
I'm not sure, but you may want to check out MTProto (Telegram API) to see if there's a way around for it as a user bot.
